# what is the format of this image value?

Tags: sql-server, database, base64

it has image datatype in the database

```
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
```

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? It's a binary value that represents *something* (maybe a file?). *If* it is a file, that won't tell you what type of file it is; as that something that the file's name (specifically the extension). The data within a file doesn't store information about what it is, or it's name, as that's handled by the file system.

Comment: @Larnu While it's true that you can't always tell a file's type by its contents, it's somewhat misleading to think of file extensions as any more reliable. In many contexts, the type is simply an explicit piece of metadata stored somewhere beside the data.

Comment: True, @IMSoP, but binary data without an extension will mean you simply playing a guessing game to find out what the file type is. When storing data like the OP has in an RDBMS you ***should*** be storing the name of the file (with an extension) and the file type in the data row too.

Comment: @Larnu That's simply not true. There is no extension in the URL for this web page, but your browser knows it's HTML, because the file type is transmitted by a different method. You need to store the file type _in some format_, but that might be a MIME type, or just "1 for JPEG, 2 for PNG", and nothing to do with the filename; or it might be that the column _always_ contains data in a particular format, so there is no need for metadata at all.

Comment: @IMSoP That's because the file has `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of the file, so the browser can see that and know. Such thing won't exist in a compiled binary file, like I said. Opening something like a `jpg` or `exe` in notepad will give you "garbage". Certainly SQL Server won't be able to infer what file type it is.

Comment: @Larnu Nope, that's not how it works at all. The web server sends a header, `Content-Type: text/html`; if you send the same content with `Content-Type: text/plain`, it will display differently; to display a PDF correctly, you send `Content-Type: application/pdf`, and so on. Notepad is actually a good counter-example: regardless of what the filename is, it will try to read the file as text, because that's all it knows how to do. An image editor might well look at the filename as a clue to the file type, but it could also look at the content to see if it matches any of the formats it supports.

Answer (score 0):

The image data type is an old data type from the Sybase days. Applications aren't supposed to use it any more.

However, all it was used for was storing BLOBs of any type, not just actual images (as in photos). There's no built-in function that's going to tell you what it was. It could be a .jpg, a .wav, a word document, anything.

If it really was an image, you could pull it in to a .NET object and use an image library to try to identify it. But you wouldn't want to be trying to do that in SQL Server. Even in SQL CLR, most of the libraries that you'd need can't be loaded. For example, you can't load System.Drawing.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments and answers have said, the `IMAGE` data type is used to store arbitrary binary data, and neither restricts nor stores any information about the meaning of that data.

The representation you have there is not base64 (as implied by your tags) but simply hexadecimal: each pair of characters after the leading `0x` represents a single byte of data.

If you extracted the value as raw bytes, or converted the hexadecimal representation back to the raw bytes, you could save it to disk as a file, and use a utility to try to guess the format. For instance, there is a standard Unix utility `file`, which has a lookup table of "signatures" for different file formats, usually the first few bytes of the file.

However, without context, this could be a binary format specific to a particular application, such as a game save state, in which case no generic tool will be able to tell you much about it. Ultimately, it's just a way of representing a long series of bits, and could be absolutely anything.